# Topic deletion from Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I have deleted topic directly from Zookeeper using the below command and did not execute deletion from Kafka before:

```
zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181 rmr /brokers/topics/<topic_name>
```

Now what I see is that the topic shows up in the `log.dirs` of at least one broker in the cluster. Is there a way that can be deleted as well.

When i attempt to delete from kafka now it throws the below error

```
Error while executing topic command : Topic <topic_name> does not exist on ZK path <zookeeper_server_list:2181>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed a couple of steps. In order to manually delete a topic you need to follow these steps:

1) Stop Kafka server

2) **On each broker**, you have you have to delete all the topic's log files under `logs.dirs`:

```
rm -rf path/to/logs/topic_name/
```

3) Remove topic directory from Zookeeper:

```
> zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:2181
> ls /brokers/topics
> rmr /brokers/topics/topic_name
```

4) Restart Kafka server

---

Note that the suggested way for deleting a topic is

```
/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --topic topic_name
```

assuming that `delete.topic.enable=true`.